# Getting a file path from a filename

Tags: javascript, fso

I need your help.

How can I use javascript to find the filepath based on a given file filename?

ie.

the function would execute to find the database.mdb to be contained in: C:\primaryfolder\database\database.mdb

```
function find_filepath("database.mbd") {
   alert(filepath)
}
```

Thanks for everyones help in advance

Much thanks and appreciation

Cheers

Jay

Comment: JavaScript? Not. IE+ Scripting.FileSystemObject` ActiveX object? Possibly. Other browser + custom plugin? Go write the plugin first.

Comment: I would recommend to read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript in modern browsers cannot directly access the filesystem. 
They are in a sandbox. You could use **IE** and **ActiveX** for what you are trying to do.